# In my <a> tag, there are lots of code HTML. How to add Html link (CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-helper

My code:

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="list_content">
      <p class="title"><?php echo $note['Note']['title']; ?></p>
      <p class="create_at"><?php echo $note['Note']['create_at'] ?></p>
      <p> <?php echo substr($note['Note']['content'], 0,100) . '...' ?></p>
   </div>
</a>
```

How to add `<?php echo $this->Html->link('...') ?>` in CAKEPHP 2.x

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert HTML element in any HTML helper, you have to add **'escape' => false**. Check the document https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link

**Simple Example:**

```
$this->Html->link('<b>My Content</b>','#',[
    'escape' => false
]);
```

**For you case:**

```
$this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->div('list_content',
        $this->Html->para('title',$note['Note']['title']).
        $this->Html->para('create_at',$note['Note']['create_at']).
        $this->Html->para(null,substr($note['Note']['content'], 0,100) . '...')
    ),
    '#',
    ['escape' => false]
);
```

Comment: If you disable `escape` you should really remember to then escape any user input using `h()`. Cake deliberately escapes the link text by default for security, so disabling this needs to be done with caution!

Comment: thank a lot, but I am using CKEditor to add content Note. When in content have tag <a>...<a/>, it will not lie in $this->Html->link('...').

Comment: how to add tag <a> in  $this->Html->link('...')

Comment: please help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768560/how-to-use-link-to-div-html-inside-div-have-another-a

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Aman's answer, remember that by setting `'escape' => false` you are disabling a default security feature. So you probably want to make sure you then escape any user input using the `h()` method:-

```
$this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->div('list_content',
        $this->Html->para('title', h($note['Note']['title'])).
        $this->Html->para('create_at', h($note['Note']['create_at'])).
        $this->Html->para(null, substr(h($note['Note']['content']), 0,100) . '...')
    ),
    '#',
    ['escape' => false]
);
```

If you've got a lot of markup you want inside your `<a>` tags it is sometimes simpler to use `$this->Html->url()` instead (and can lead to more readable code):-

```
<a href="<?= $this->Html->url('#') ?>">
  <div class="list_content">
      <p class="title"><?php echo $note['Note']['title']; ?></p>
      <p class="create_at"><?php echo $note['Note']['create_at'] ?></p>
      <p> <?php echo substr($note['Note']['content'], 0,100) . '...' ?></p>
   </div>
</a>
```

The only real disadvantage I am aware of doing this second example is that you lose any functionality that you may add to `$this->Html->link()`, but I suspect this isn't a concern for the majority of users.